# Why Android Studio Design UI isn't showing my views properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

All views I drag and drop aren’t showing up, not even the default “Hello World” one! This is driving me crazy!!! I can select the views (for ex. a Button) that I already added by clicking and dragging on the top left corner of the Design UI, but can't see them what so ever! I created new projects with different APIs nothing is working, I even uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled again but didn't help either.

The screen share of whats happening: https://drive.google.com/open?id=182dD2DB3bK8TSZUKUTzBX9EhFiQ6cp0U

Comment: Please note that I only started android studio about a week or two ago, so I am still an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have an error there. If you click on that red icon, you will be prompt with the option to refresh the layout to correctly render it. The refresh should work.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Also, an alternative would be to downgrade the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion o 27 in order to use a stable version of appcompat, like  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0

Comment: I did refresh the layout but it didn't help. Here are the screenshots for more details:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e3_rkZvihGbriK01J13X4No3cCFWSV9_
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oOIAaUgiiNJrS4HnDKODwcLgoMk_e5QI

Comment: Did you hit the "refresh" button? http://snpy.in/aApLDs Because on your screenshots, you still have the red icon indicating that there is still an error.

Comment: The error persisted even after hitting the refresh button (I did hit there refresh word shown in the tip of the error, I don't really know where the actual button exists) But anyway when I hit that word it shows a little loading indicator and the design UI but then its gone and nothing happens.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J1ZvxfsUWxzf_3beI30s5Ldd014zf5zL

Comment: What's the support app compat version? (on your build.gradle file).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14jTLPnQdO_Xg1v9oyFsA6NGH1j8NdzsK


Incase isn't clear in the screenshot: 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Comment: Try changing it to a stable version (maybe com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0) Or, on the version dropdown, decrease the API level to 27:
http://snpy.in/icttNb

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V_EnFMZBiP1xEeT_JpICxMltyiW2bBcH


it says i cant change it to anything different than 28 because of the SDK version, should I use another SDK version?

p.s: decreasing the api as u cleared in the pic didn't help (i did refresh the layout multiple times, still same issue)

Comment: Yes. You need to decrease the targetSdkVersion to 27 as well

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it the views show up now properly BUT: the Design UI is quite laggy, it was so smooth before (I am running it on Mini PC Intel® NUC Kit NUC6i7KYK). 

P.S: there is an error still present in the gradle files at the app compat version as you can see in the screen shot.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LIlWWKEwLZiDQ0cagemzhKNPaUPbJ6_n

Comment: Can't do much about the lag. Could just be a coincidence. In order to remove that error, you need to set the compileSdkVersion to 27 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your XML. Switch to the `Text` tab at the bottom to get more details.

[image]

Comment: The errors are because the views are not constrained. But as you can see in the video, the default Hello World TextView is already constrained in the middle by default, also I tried constraining the Button View and that didn't help either.
Here are the screenshots for the Text tab.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e3_rkZvihGbriK01J13X4No3cCFWSV9_
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oOIAaUgiiNJrS4HnDKODwcLgoMk_e5QI